# What should I do when I spot a user who is up-voting their alternate account

Tags: discussion, users, moderation, multiple-accounts

The user [Suresh Siva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465774/suresh-siva) has 5 answers, each of them marked as answered and up-voted exactly once, all of them answers to questions asked by the user [Suresh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398893/suresh).

In fact in at least [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656543/cocos2d-set-mousepoint-to-sprite-co-ordinate/4012539#4012539) is simply an exact copy-paste of the code from another users answer.

What should I do in such situations?  Is it enough to mark one of the posts for moderator attention, or should it be posted here?

Comment: Shame..! Shame..! Shame..!

Comment: He's been continuing to do this [systematically](http://stackoverflow.com/users/465774?tab=activity) since this has been posted (he's at 9 accepted answers already). Seeing that his answers are not only accepted, but upvoted *twice* within minutes of being posted, there's a third account involved: [Renya](http://stackoverflow.com/users/453481/renya). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804432) and [this particularly blatant rip-off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758297) of someone else's answer.

Comment: It's a conspiracy!  (S)He's been busy, as of now, 17 answers to questions (all accepted) from the "sock puppet" accounts with the combined question count, 17!  Totally gaming the system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mark for moderator attention will be enough. You can also mail the team.

Its not a user task to judge other users. That task belongs to the mods.

Comment: Replace 'user' with 'human' and 'moderator' with 'god' :-P

Comment: I have seen moderators act like gods. But that's not the issue. In the case users had to be judged (because of their behaviour) its not a task that can be achieved with gaining rep.

Comment: @Lars Udengaard: ...and your point is? Theology and mythology aside, who has the tools to do something about the situation (e.g. have access to moderator tools, can send an e-mail directly to the user in question, or in severe cases, can give time outs)? Not the users.

Answer (score 2):

User [Renya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453481/renya) looks like his other sock puppet.  He's been busy, got himself on the #5 spot in the user leagues.