# Stack Overflow is not accepting questions from my account anymore

Tags: support, status-bydesign, asking-questions, post-ban

I can't post a question when logged in via OpenID on Stack Overflow. How can I do it?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a really bad error description. Tell us what happens when you try to post a question and what errors you get.

Comment: @sth - Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

    * Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

This is the message i got while i post the question

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: Yes, that is a severe communication problem indeed :) You might have to retitle this one again, based on the OP's comment.

Comment: @Jose: Done. Hope you like that better.

Comment: @sth: You suck at investigating sock-puppets!

Comment: @Jeff: http://stackoverflow.com/users/303456/sri - http://stackoverflow.com/users/486197/sribharanidharan - http://stackoverflow.com/users/455990/sribharanidharan

Comment: @Ladybug: I deleted my comment.  I thought you were linking to the person discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68494/what-should-i-do-when-i-spot-a-user-who-is-up-voting-their-alternate-account) where the profile pages looked strikingly similar.

Comment: Thanks to all now i can post question

Comment: i m sorry ,but how did you fixed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account.

This error message means that you've been asking poorly written and researched questions, so we don't want any more questions from you.

This is a permanent ban. It not only blocks your account, but also the IP address you were using. To prevent bypassing [the filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294), its exact details are not public. It is partly based on downvotes, and downvotes on deleted questions are also taken into account. (An account with a high public reputation might very well have many deleted questions, including [auto-deleted old low-score questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year), all of which are only visible to moderators.)

Comment: Apparently 50% accept rate and two questions with -4 votes (three with +1) are enough to "silence" an user. A bit too harsh, maybe?

Comment: @Esko good point. Especially as the two -4 questions show an interest in learning. There are much, much worse questions on SO that get less downvotes than that

Comment: I agree with Esko, but it's IP based also (I think), so maybe be poor questions from another account affecting the silencing?

Comment: @kop - it may be my fault to ask the question without any format but i was new to SO when i post that question. give me the solution

Comment: @Peter I think if it says "from that account" it is targeted at that user

Comment: @Esko ya that -4 questions are informal question it my fault only but i have no idea to ask the questions in proper format

Comment: @Esko: I think the mechanism also accounts for deleted questions of which there may be more...

Comment: @Tobias true, but questions are rarely deleted. @sri try sending an E-Mail to `team@stackoverflow.com` and ask them to let your account back in.

Comment: @Pekka: He uses several sock-puppet accounts. I guess his account is disabled for a reason.

Comment: @Ladybug oh! That changes things entirely of course. (unless the creating of sock-puppet accounts started after the block, which is something I could kind of understand.)

Comment: @Ladybug -  ya i forgot my password so i created two more account its not my mistake i think so.....

Comment: @sri you will need to talk to the SO team. No one of us here has the power to lift the block, we can only voice our opinions on it.

Comment: @Pekka thanks for you kindly help thanks to all for kind information

Comment: Funny how possibly a genuine confused/scared user can be perceived *evil* because of our love (as a civilization) to [dumb down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumbing_down) things. :)

Comment: @Ashish: the block is done automatically, and you can't detect intent automatically, so it's one of the downsides which I assumed were deemed acceptable.

Comment: @Kop: Yes, to scale we do need to dumb down. My comment was on a philosophical note, we as a civilization have come so far (from caves to skyscrapers) and yet dumbing down is our best bet. :)

Comment: LOL i have been permantly banned from meta too !!! damn I just wanted to brag out the fact I am above Jon Skeet acutally lol http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2011-06-01/496223#496223

Comment: Is there anyway to recover from this ban?