# Question suggestion overzealous, fellas

Tags: bug, status-completed, similar-questions

Apparently the question suggestion feature was updated lately. I like the copy: "Questions that may already have your answer". The list of suggestions seems....exorbitant.

[image]

Didn't that list used to be limited to 5 questions? 10 questions would be a lot. This is a bit more than overkill (and dropped the question body box clear below the fold on a 1080p monitor!). I repro'd this on Cog Sci Meta and MetaSO, UX, seems to be everywhere.

Comment: I like this approach. If you want to ask a question, we make you read 7 to 10 pages of loosely related questions. This'll cut down on bad questions for sure!

Comment: I'm speculating that it might be related to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132048/revamping-the-duplicate-question-system), but it could easily be a bug too.

Comment: @TimStone the copy was definitely edited, I'm guessing the CSS might have been tweaked (and borked) in the process

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're working on the results here (much cleaner format in the works) and a `style="title-search-container"` crept in rewrite, instead of `class="title-search-container"`, our bad.

A fix for this is being built/deployed right now, it should be resolved across the network in a few minutes.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's missing CSS. If I remember correctly, that area used to have a `max-height` and `overflow:auto`. Did <s>balpha</s> rchern break something..?

I believe this fixes it:

```
.title-search-container {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: If true, that would do it

Comment: Yeah, I saw this earlier today and thought "I wonder why they uncollapsed this."

Comment: I still blame balpha. Actually wait, no, I blame [Becksta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff)!

Comment: There's enough blame to blame *both* of them.

Comment: lmao@Pekka. Just remember at least one of them [has evil powers](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/rchern-strikes-back).

Comment: The CSS is already there...it's the lack of a class on the element if you do a double take :)