# Related questions dialog is way too big

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question suggestion overzealous, fellas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135143/question-suggestion-overzealous-fellas)

[image]

I believe this accurately represents my problem.

Happens on SO proper as well (not sure about other SE sites).

Comment: +1 Happened to me today, too.

Comment: This will cause people not to look through related questions at all.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135143/158428

Comment: Ironically, it wasn't suggested *even in the over super long thing*.

Comment: @DeadMG LMAO +1