# Why can I edit out the Possible Duplicate Banner from this question?

Tags: discussion, bug, duplicate-questions

Normally, I don't see an edit in the revision history where the possible duplicate banner is added after someone  votes to close a question but take a look at [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/28042/revisions), not only can I view the banner being added but I can also edit it out of the post.

Comment: Well, you can't edit out this one. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Really???. I just did http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/125158/revisions

Comment: @Tijesunimi **Any** post which was closed as a duplicate using the old system (before ~February 2013) will be like that.

Comment: @Tijesunimi I mean the dupe banner on this very question you asked 7 minutes ago here. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @ShadowWizard I clearly misunderstood and was busy disturbing the front page. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the past, Community would actually edit that message into a post when it was closed as a duplicate, as can be seen in Revision 2 of that post.

> [image: screenshot of revision 2]

This behaviour was changed as part of [last year's large overhaul of the closing system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux).

Answer (score 3):

A long time ago, the duplicate banner was part of the question itself. It used to get automatically added by the Community user the moment the question is closed as such.

[Not anymore though.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132048/revamping-the-duplicate-question-system) It's now a separate entity that normal users can't touch. (at least not without reopening the question)

Comment: Note also that at the time that specific question was closed, the "auto-inserted" comment was not added with the duplicate notice, so it never got automatically removed when reopened either.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, Community actually added in the duplicate link in the second edit. Community used to do this, now it is not part of the source, but an external force that we can't do anything about unless we open the question