# What happens when you reach zero flag weight?

Tags: support, flag-weight

Marc Gravell [wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117):

> **IMPORTANT CHANGE** - if you flag so consistently badly that you reach 0 weight, flags will be suppressed

What happens exactly when one *does* reach flag weight zero?

- Does your daily flag allowance simply drop to zero?
- Do you get a message similar to "[we are no longer accepting questions from this account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68616/so-is-not-accepting-questions-from-my-account-anymore)"?
- Do your flags get silently ignored?
- Can you ever go back to the land of the flagging?

Comment: When did Marc suddenly turn into a kind of stone?

Comment: Ah, I thought he had a stare-out with Medusa :)

Answer (score 21):

When you reach zero flag weight, you can still flag normally and you still get your base flag allowance. You will get no message about this.

However, *no* moderator flags you make will make it to the moderators' flag list.*

<sub>* Unless some other user with non-zero flag weight also flags a post you're flagging, in which case both flags will be shown. Still, your flags will not be dismissed with the other flag, so in essence you can't get positive flag weight anymore.</sub>

Comment: This is great, but... citation needed.

Comment: @Popular Own research. This post is the citation.

Answer (score 0):

Surely all that happens is that a practice that you are bad at (flagging) stops being something that affects anything.  Which suggests that someone who runs this site is able to apply machine-learning - which is probably a good idea, given the volume of data.

My second guess has something to do with a zero flag causes a divide-by-zero exception - but one of the developers has stuck in a line like:

```
on error goto 0
```

My third guess involves the gravitational collapse of the SO account under its own weight of ineptitude, causing the generation of the SO version of a super red dwarf.  But perhaps that guess is influenced by the fact that [the Indie Manc Professor has a new series on telly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Cox_(physicist)).