# Answer mimics OP's own comment of resolution, flag for non-answer?

Tags: discussion, flags

[Answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773981/eclipse-giving-an-error-of-android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout-failed-to-instan/11267004#11267004)

> Same problem here, updating java also solved the problem.

given that the OP posted a [comment stating resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773981/eclipse-giving-an-error-of-android-support-v7-widget-gridlayout-failed-to-instan/11267004#comment14059890_10773981) a month earlier.

> Thanks for your efforts to help guys, but nothing was working. But, finally found the solution. EXTREMELY embarrassed to say that I needed to update the JAVA on my machine. Apologies...

My personal judgement would call this answer a comment following the OP's, caused by the fact that the 1-rep user can't post comments yet. But at the same time "update your java install/make sure your java install is up to date" is the actual answer and the OP could decide to accept this answer, possibly after having it rewritten a bit to "make sure your java install is up-to-date".

Would I be right in my reasoning of flagging as "not an answer"? I realise this is quite a trivial question but I'd rather not send another false flag into the heap. So I'd rather ask here first.

Comment: BZZT!  Baleeted.  Flag dismissed as helpful.  Oh, those silly new users, thinking they've stumbled into yet another online forum.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But it would be nice to know the rules for flaggers.

Comment: Rules: 1. flag if you think it needs to be flagged 2. ??? 3. Profit

Comment: that's the point of flags, to get a moderator to look at it.  If the moderator agrees, he/she will take action.

Comment: Will my flags be considered "oh it's that dummy again" if I have a few denied flags? I've read about flag weight but what I've read stated also that it's no longer in play?

Comment: You've only had a couple of declined flags, so I wouldn't worry.

Comment: See [this answer about declined flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135105/what-are-the-bad-things-if-any-associated-with-the-declined-flag-count/135116#135116). You have to get a lot of declined flags compared to helpful for it to matter. If at least half of your flags are helpful you have nothing to worry about

Comment: As an aside "Same Problem" is a good phrase to look for if you're [actively looking for things to flag](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/53861/posts-that-could-be-marked-as-not-an-answer-to-help-get-the-marshal-badge)

Comment: thank you for that but I'd have to read up on data.se to use it. In any case I'm not really hunting for flags, just going over the posts I find in review to try and help out and get a better idea on what makes a good answer and question. I've learned some things already by seeing how others formulate things, so for me it's worthwile.