# what is the effect of declined flag on user profile?

Tags: support, flag-weight, declined-flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the “Bad Things,” if any, associated with the declined flag count?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135105/what-are-the-bad-things-if-any-associated-with-the-declined-flag-count)

Earlier when we flag some thing and the flag is **declined**, then it had a negative effect on the flag weight. Now that we cannot see any flag weight displayed in profile, if I do a wrong flag what effect will it produce on the flagging privilege?

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135105/what-are-the-bad-things-if-any-associated-with-the-declined-flag-count/135116#135116)

Comment: @BenBrocka Actually, I think this question is pretty much a duplicate of the one you linked to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has the same effect on your flagging privilege.  The flag weight and all is still there, it's just invisible. So too many declined flags will affect the sorting of your flags, and if your flag weight goes too low, your flags are never displayed in the list. Also (h/t jadarnel27), the number of flags you get per day is affected by this.

Too many people got worked up about flag weight, and thus [it was made hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84859/we-dont-need-to-see-flag-weight/119709#119709) (although all of the [rules for flag weight calculation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117) still apply).

Comment: In addition to flag queue ordering, it also affects how many flags you get per day still.

Comment: Also worth to mention [those rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117) are still valid and in place.

Comment: *Vanity upvote!*

Comment: @jadarnel thanks :) Also, thanks for the edits, I find it hard to gopher for links from a tablet :\

Comment: I figured you were on your mobile, so I'd add them for you =)  I don't know why I didn't do that in the first place anyway.