# Is there any feature to stop a user from flagging if he has an unsuccessful flagging history

Tags: discussion, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the “Bad Things,” if any, associated with the declined flag count?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135105/what-are-the-bad-things-if-any-associated-with-the-declined-flag-count)

I just wanted to know if there is any facility within the system to identify a user having a **low successful flagging history**. By low successful flagging history I mean the percentage of flags that were eligible to be acted on over total flags by the user. Because if a user uses all his flags daily unnecessarily it will take a long time by moderators to clean up the mess.

So there should be a facility to spot such users and stop them from flagging if their rate of success is too low in a given period of time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you get too many flags declined your flag weight (which isn't shown but still exists) will hit 0. ([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117))

This makes your flags invisible to other users. The only way your flag weight will increase from that position is if other users also flag the same post to bring it to moderators attention in which case the flag will get acted on still.

In short mechanisms exist to avoid abuse and problems like this.