# Flagged questions for review gone to limbo

Tags: support, status-completed, flags

Recently I had done some flagging of questions as "not a real question".

And three of them have been in waiting for review for quiet long time (4 days to be precise), This is my user account.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/386161/guru-kara

I think it has gone to some sort of queue which is not visible to moderators or this is a bug.

Comment: You may check your flag history from your profile. Did you check it? May be your flags are rejected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, it's the weekend and we're a little (read: *very*) caught up.

Since you asked here and it's just a small handful of flags on questions that haven't received much attention after those 4 days, I've gone ahead and cleared them for you.

Remember that you can always check the status of your flags by clicking the number next to "helpful flags" in your profile. If your flags have been in review for a few days, chances are there are so many flags on our backlog that we may easily have missed yours (especially considering that these are "close question" or "it doesn't belong here" flags), or we're just really busy. It's highly unlikely to be a bug, so there is little, if any, need to report it here.

The *only* way that your flags will not be seen by moderators is through attaining a *horrendous* track record for flagging by having a high ratio of declined flags to helpful flags. You're nowhere near this threshold, so you don't have to worry about your flags getting lost in limbo.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation :))

Comment: Did you mean that you were a little behind? I can't think of a time in my life when I got *caught up* on anything over a weekend.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that if you flagged a bunch of stuff inappropriately and had your flags denied. your [flag weight has dropped to zero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82445/145951) and your flags are no longer showing up anywhere. You should pay careful attention to any feedback you receive from denied flags.

On the other hand, it's possible that the flag queue is just a couple days behind.