# Did I ask any bad questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked many questions (68) and some perhaps were not very good; my account is https://stackoverflow.com/users/108207/niklas-r.

I'd agree to deleting 2 of my own questions since there isn't a solution to the first question and the second question is too localized.

1. [Django Form Preview with google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951732/django-form-preview-with-google-app-engine)
   (Downvoted perhaps since it's a discussion how to do it with other
   components than Django.)
2. [Why is my django snippet not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881897/why-is-my-django-snippet-not-working)
   (It is solved but too localized.)

Do you agree with deleting these 2 questions? I deleted other questions I asked, but it could ban the account from asking again, and I really like being able to ask questions. Please comment, or tell me your experience.

Comment: Let me try to understand, are you afraid that if you delete some of your questions, that you will be banned from asking more questions?

Comment: Yes, @Marcelo, deleting questions [could be an indication](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029) that those were apparently of low quality.

Comment: Exactly. I don't think anybody would care about the 2 questions I linked to for example and if I delete them myself I might can banned so I'm asking here for advice and your opinion. Thank you

Comment: I'd hope you are not in risk of being banned having answered 133 questions. You've given back plenty which is great...that would provide much sway in your favour...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with asking 68 questions, as long as they're high-quality questions likely to be useful to other people. And there's *especially* nothing wrong with it if you've taken the time to provide good answers to other people's questions (as you have).

So I say, feel free to delete a handful of the lower-quality questions you've asked that you *don't* think will be helpful to others (because they're too localized, for example). I don't know exactly what the algorithm is for an automatic question ban, but if it *were* to happen, I think you have a solid case for emailing the team and having your abilities re-instated.

I don't really feel qualified to comment on the specific questions you've highlighted, as I know *nothing* about Django, so this is intentionally a pretty generic answer. But overall, it's quite unlikely that someone with a history of solid contributions will trip the ban by deleting a couple of questions/answers.

That said, don't feel *obligated* to delete questions just because you've already solved the issue or it seems like a "dumb" question in the first place. Those questions might still be useful to someone else in the future searching for a solution to the same problem. Make sure that you post a *good* answer explaining your realization of your mistake, or how you solved the problem, and accept it when the system eventually allows you to do so. You only need to delete *bad* questions, things that are actively harmful to keep around or are *guaranteed* to be useless to future visitors.

"Good" questions are not the same as "hard" questions. Good questions are those that make sense, address a specific programming-related problem, can be definitively answered, and are likely to help others in the future. If you've asked those, *keep them* and don't ever feel embarrassed that you asked them. Learning new things in a conscientious and productive way is just as important and impressive, if not more so, than appearing that you know everything already!