# Should I vote to "delete" one of my posts if it gets no replies, to avoid its effect on my "accept rate"?

Tags: support, accept-rate, self-delete

Should I vote to "delete" one of my posts if it gets no replies, to avoid it affects my accept rate?

If not, what is recommended way to avoid negative impact on accept rate?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the concept of "accept rate" has long been removed from the system and this is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If your post doesn't get any replies, it [doesn't count against your accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work).  How could you accept something that isn't there?  There's nothing to worry about with it.

Comment: Somehow, Jeremy posted the same but then deleted it 10 minutes ago. I think you're right, but that deletion makes me wonder. Jeremy?

Comment: @Arjan See the top answer in the FAQ: `Which questions do not affect the accept rate? The following questions are not included in the accept rate calculation: <snip> *Questions with no answers*`

Comment: @Greg In addition to the fact that unanswered questions don't count against your accept rate, note that if you delete too many of your own questions you are significantly increasing your risk of being *banned.* Your accept rate definitely isn't that important. :)

Comment: Of course, if you delete too many in too short of a time period, you may get yourself postbanned by the system.

Answer (score 5):

No, accept rate isn't that important.  If you want an answer to your question, then leave it up and work it.  You could put a bounty on it.

Comment: it's been up for a few weeks however - just leave it open ongoing?  even if after 3 months say?  e.g.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328234/does-iphone-simulator-calendar-store-availability-correctly-for-an-event

Comment: @Greg, just leaving it probably won't garner anything, but you can work it by editing it with more information, as you've tried to solve the problem yourself, and adding a bounty.

Answer (score 4):

When you vote to delete your own questions without any reply, you are effectively deleting them. Consider that deleting too much questions have a negative effect, [as far as I remember](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029).

If your questions don't get any answer, you can offer a bounty on them. Remember you can offer three bounties on different questions at the same time.

Comment: I was sure I read about that, but I didn't remember where I have read it. Thank you for the link. `:-)`

Comment: "As far as I remember" is not authoritative enough! But I won't take away the upvote ;-)

Answer (score 3):

New users should avoid doing this at all costs.  While the exact algorithm is kept locked in the vault with the recipe for New Coke and the Colonel's 11 secret herbs and spices, it is generally understood that if a new user has three or more questions deleted within a short period of time, they will likely be [banned from asking further questions by the system.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

Comment: Ah, "three or more"? In [Should I avoid deleting my questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029) Jeff states: *A typical amount of question deletion on an account (say, 10% of your questions) is no problem*. Of course, new users @Won't have too many questions, so "three or more" might very well be much more than 10%, but still curious about the source for that figure!

Comment: @Arjan: If I told you, I'd have to etc etc.

Comment: But now you kind of told everybody! You cannot etc etc all of us! (Still, feel welcome to visit the Netherlands!)

Comment: Are the 23 flavors of Dr. Pepper there, too?

Answer (score 1):

The accept rate takes into consideration only non-CW questions with answers.