# Close inactive question to improve accepted ratio?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I vote to “delete” one of my posts if it gets no replies, to avoid its effect on my “accept rate”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107888/should-i-vote-to-delete-one-of-my-posts-if-it-gets-no-replies-to-avoid-its-ef)

I have on occasion had quite a number of questions I have left open despite having responses to them because they are not the right answer. After a while, this starts to affect one's accepted ratio. Should one care? [Here's an example of such a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271665/force-screen-redraw-other-than-using-removechild-and-then-addchild-to-get-im); not a bad question, just highly specific and hard to answer definitively.

Do I close the question? I don't think editing it will do much good - not much more I can do there anyway.

What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't worry about accept rate much, if you're accepting answers that are correct and helpful to you, you're already doing everything you should. There is no need to go any further and accept answers that don't solve your problem and that are not helpful to you.

The accept mark means the answer was helpful to you, you really shouldn't worry about any other implications of it.

Keep in mind that questions without upvoted answers are not counted for your accept rate.