# I want to ask a question!

Tags: support, asking-questions, question-restrictions

Lately, I have wanted to ask an important question about WP7 developing on Stack Overflow. I have been answering as many questions as I can, and my reputation is 79. How much reputation do I need in order to prove myself worthy of asking questions on Stack Overflow again?

Comment: Are you seeing "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"? If yes, then what is not clear about the help [you are being referred to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi/86998#86998)?

Comment: @Arjan he only has 2 questions... that doesn't totally make sense... Oh, unless it's his IP that's banned, I see...

Comment: Sure [it does, or might](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029), @The ;-)

Comment: @Arjan Ahhh I don't have 10K on SO so I can't see if there were many questions deleted... parioscreations, did you have a lot of questions before? Did you delete them?

Comment: (@The, with 10k folks cannot see deleted questions either, unless one *knows* the URL. Moderators can see a list though. But Google's [November 22nd cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:fg9-S-intgMJ:stackoverflow.com/users/640428/parioscreations+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk) only shows 2 as well.)

Comment: What? Really @Arjan? I didn't realize that. But the google cache is very helpful. My guess is this is a shared IP or something? **parioscreations, what is the actual error message you receive?**

Comment: Yeah, knowing the error message you're getting would be helpful. I don't see anything particularly out of order on your account.

Comment: As a moderator, you *could* see an overview of the user's deleted questions, right @Anna? (So we can assume that lots of deleted questions are not the cause of a question ban, if there is such ban?)

Comment: @Arjan There are no deleted questions on the account.

Comment: It seems as if I can ask questions again! Thanks for the help everyone!
And I believe the error was WE ARE NO LONGER ACCEPTING QUESTIONS FROM THIS ACCOUNT.