# Deleted an Unaccepted question, still getting counted in accept rate

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
>   [How does accept rate work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

I had an unaccepted question for several weeks that I finally abandoned hope of getting a working answer to (A non working answer had been given). I deleted it, hoping my accept rate would return to 100%, but that doesn't seem to have happened. Is it stuck like this?

Comment: Don't delete a question just because you want to improve your acceptance rate.  Your acceptance rate doesn't need to be 100%. If a question is good, but hasn't gotten an answer yet, try offering a bounty.

Comment: How long have you waited? These things don't update immediately.  From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work): "The accept rate is heavily cached and can take 24hrs or more to update."

Comment: I'd assume it's because just by deleting the question, it still *exists* on the system, so you'd probably have to wait for a recache before the system would determine not to include that question. From my experience, just accepting an answer produces immediate results.

Comment: And as for @tvanfosson's comment: [very true](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your accept rate is calculated on the fly when you *accept or unaccept* an answer, either triggers a recalc immediately.  We also recalc an accept rate when merging/unmerging user accounts...aside from that **the calculation also runs once a day for all users**, that's the one you have to wait for when dealing with deleted content.

If you look now you'll see your accept rate is correct, since the nightly sync job has run.