# How can I delete my own question with a low score but with answers?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I want to delete the question which has a low score. How can I delete my own question which has got a low score but has one or two answers?

Comment: You can't directly. If you have really found it to be terrible enough to be removed and you can't instead improve it, you might flag it for moderator attention and explain the situation. But try to improve it first.

Comment: No, [as the answerers invested time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471), deleting is not appreciated [and might even get you a ban for wasting *readers* time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029) if deleted when no answers were posted.

Comment: @Bart I flagged that question. But it was declined by the moderators with the reason: flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Comment: Beware that, once posted, [you agreed](http://stackexchange.com/legal/) *"that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license"* and cannot easily remove it. There are requests to [have one's name removed from content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said) though.

Comment: As for removing your name, that requires another flag: [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC:WIKI?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki)

Comment: If you are talking about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877770/fetch-email-programmatically-by-providing-server-name-and-port) then to be honest it is a dog of a question and is the sort of question that SO strives to avoid - a simple Google search would have provided you with a lot of answers. Take it as a lesson, ask better questions next time. Overall it isn't an issue, it doesn't affect your stats that much.

Comment: i want to do it as i dont want unnecessary questions.

Comment: That's really up to the community to decide.