# What should I do if I realize the premise of a question was faulty, but I already have answers?

Tags: support, question-quality

The question in question is this: [SSHing git@github.com shows wrong/old SSH key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563936/sshing-gitgithub-com-shows-wrong-old-ssh-key).

I had assumed wrongly that the SSH key fingerprint displayed when you're SSHing into GitHub for example, should match your own Public RSA key. After reading the answers, I realized it was simply GitHub's own Public key's fingerprint (so as to authenticate the host you're trying to connect to).

Since the question is wrongly framed, I can't really accept any answer (which would lower my accept-percentage BTW, so it's not like I don't want to give away reputation). I can't delete it either as it says *"Sorry, this question has one more answers; flag it for moderator attention instead"*, even though its *my* question; I guess this is because, as it says in [How can I delete my own question with a low score but with answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138981/how-can-i-delete-my-own-question-with-a-low-score-but-with-answers) I'd have wasted reader's time.

I don't want to lose reputation, nor do I want to turn Stack Overflow into a big pile of junk.

What should I do, without losing reputation (if possible)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What said from Mr Lister is correct, but I would point out that [Miguel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11564948/225647) actually answers your question, when it says:

> But maybe it is not a problem, as *Step 5: Test everything out* of your link says that you may see this warning:
>
> ```
> # The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
> # RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
> # Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
> ```
>
> and you shouldn't worry, this is supposed to happen. Just verify that the fingerprint matches the one here and type "yes".

I cannot say if Stack Overflow's moderators delete questions in such cases, when there is an answer, and the question doesn't have a negative score. You could try by flagging it for moderation attention, saying that you discovered you made a false assumption, and the question would not help any future reader (which means the question is not relevant for you, nor for future readers). It could be deleted, if they think the question effectively doesn't help any future reader.

I had some of my questions deleted from Meta Stack Overflow. Once, I have explained the question was not anymore relevant as I was reporting something true for an old version of Safari (the browser) that was not anymore used from me, or any other user; in another occasion, I explained the feature request seemed only relevant for me, and no other users seemed interested in it.
I guess the important is to give a detailed explanation, not a too generic explanation.

Comment: Indeed, the question was answered and hence, even if not useful for the OP, might help future visitors who misinterpret the error message as well. Simply perfect for a Q&A site!

Answer (score 3):

Flag it for moderator attention mentioning that "Answer should be deleted because it doesn't make sense and is therefore not suitable for the Q&A format".

You do have one upvote on the question currently, so you'd lose 5 rep if it really gets deleted. You can vote to close instead, but if it does get closed, it might get deleted later on, with the same result.

Mind you, deleting too many questions is frowned upon by the system and may result in question banning in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Your question could still be valuable to someone else who has the same incorrect assumption you did. If you thought this, it's almost certain someone else does. You could answer your own question with the edit you added at the bottom and accept it as the answer.