# Deleting old no-answer questions?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, post-ban

I deleted some old questions of mine with no answers from stackoverflow.com.

Is this OK?, as I don't want a question ban.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Should I avoid deleting my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86982/295232)